# Event listeners not working with dynamically created buttons, using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I'm creating button elements through Javascript after each li element. However, event listeners are not working for these buttons. Event listeners bound to button with text "Enter", which is already in the HTML and not dynamically created work fine. Hence, I believe the problem has something to do with my creating of buttons using Javascript. I suspect this can be solved by event delegation, but I'm lost as to how.

Following is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook
        </li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my Javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var shoppingItem = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
    return li;
}

function addElementAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();    
    }
}

function addElementAfterPress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addLineThroughEvent(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    element.classList.toggle("done");
    });
}

function addDeleteButton(element) {
    var del = document.createElement("button");
    del.addEventListener("click", function () { // This doesn't work
        alert("You clicked")
    })
    del.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
    element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", del.outerHTML);
}

input.addEventListener("keypress", addElementAfterPress);

Array.from(shoppingItem).forEach(addLineThroughEvent);

Array.from(shoppingItem).forEach(addDeleteButton);

button.addEventListener("click", addElementAfterClick);
```

I know I can solve this using jQuery. However, I need to be able to solve this using Javascript.

Comment: Is the issue that the elements created in `createListElement()` don't have events? Because if so, you're not attaching events to them. They're being set in the beginning but not for future elements

Comment: The shoppingItem collection from your getElementsByTagName() is only going to have the matching items that existed at the time that method was called. Are you trying to ensure that the events are added to new LI elements added via the createListElement call? If so, you probably want to call addLineThroughEvent and addDeleteButton inside the createListElement function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the button HTML only which does not include the event listens. You need to append the DOM element for the button using `insertAdjacentElement`.
Also, you need to call `addDeleteButton` after dynamically adding `li`

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var shoppingItem = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    ul.appendChild(li);
    addDeleteButton(li)
    input.value = "";
    return li;
}

function addElementAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();    
    }
}

function addElementAfterPress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addLineThroughEvent(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    element.classList.toggle("done");
    });
}

function addDeleteButton(element) {
    var del = document.createElement("button");
    del.addEventListener("click", function () { // This doesn't work
        alert("You clicked")
    })
    del.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
    element.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", del);
}

input.addEventListener("keypress", addElementAfterPress);

Array.from(shoppingItem).forEach(addLineThroughEvent);

Array.from(shoppingItem).forEach(addDeleteButton);

button.addEventListener("click", addElementAfterClick);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook
        </li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the events after creating the nodes in createListElement

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var shoppingItem = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
addDeleteButton(li);
addLineThroughEvent(li);
    return li;
}

function addElementAfterClick() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();    
    }
}

function addElementAfterPress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addLineThroughEvent(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    element.classList.toggle("done");
    });
}

function addDeleteButton(element) {
    var del = document.createElement("button");
    del.addEventListener("click", function () { // This doesn't work
        alert("You clicked")
    })
    del.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
    element.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", del);
}

input.addEventListener("keypress", addElementAfterPress);

Array.from(shoppingItem).forEach(addLineThroughEvent);

Array.from(shoppingItem).forEach(addDeleteButton);

button.addEventListener("click", addElementAfterClick);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook
        </li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```